# Differentiability on $\mathbb{R}^n$ under an equivalence relation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, real-numbers

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable. Given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $f:\mathbb{R}^n/\sim \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n/\sim$ also differentiable?

The question that made me consider this is as follows:

Given the 2-sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ (as a manifold), consider the stereographic projection defined in the usual way, e.g. from the 'South pole' as
\begin{align}
P_S:\mathbb{S}^2\setminus (0,0,-1) &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2
\\ (x, y, z) &\longmapsto (\frac{x}{1+z}, \frac{y}{1+z}).
\end{align}
With a similarly defined maps $P_N$ for the 'North pole', this gives us an atlas on $\mathbb{S}^2$ (they are smoothly compatible charts), and so we can talk about differentiability.

Now define the equivalence relation for $x, x'\in \mathbb{S}^2$
\begin{align}
x\sim x' \iff x = -x.
\end{align}

Now we can define
\begin{align}
P_S':\mathbb{S}^2\setminus (0,0,-1)/\sim &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\sim'
\\ [(x, y, z)] &\longmapsto [(\frac{x}{1+z}, \frac{y}{1+z})],
\end{align}
where given $(\frac{x}{1+z}, \frac{y}{1+z}), a\in \mathbb{R}^2$, define
\begin{align}
(\frac{x}{1+z}, \frac{y}{1+z}) \sim' a \iff a = (-\frac{x}{1-z}, -\frac{y}{1-z}).
\end{align}

Together with the analogous $P_N'$ (although I don't know if this is necessary any longer, since $(0,0,-1)\sim(0,0,1)$), this provides charts for  $\mathbb{S}^2/\sim$.

Assuming there is a function $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^2)$, then if $f(x) = f(-x) \forall x\in \mathbb{S}^2$, then it seems to me that this function would be well defined on $\mathbb{S}^2/\sim$. i.e. define $f'\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^2/\sim):[(x, y, z)] \mapsto f(x, y, z)$.

Is this correct? And if $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{S}^2$, will it be differentiable on $\mathbb{S}^2/\sim$?

Comment: We should first ascertain in what sense $f$ induces a map between the quotient spaces and, more importantly, in what sense a function between those quotient spaces could be seen as "differentiable".

Comment: I don't know what exactly is meant by differentiability of a function on $\mathbb{R}^n / \sim$. One usually defines differentiability for function on $R^n$, not on general sets. But it seems that under an equivalence relation a function does not even remain single valued, for instead $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$, under the equivalence relation that $x=2$ is equivalent to $x=3$, we get that $f(x)=4$ and also $f(x)=9$. This is not even a function, so I can't imagine it would be possible to say that it is in some sense differentiable..

Comment: I will edit my question to add the situation that motivated my question, perhaps it will be clearer.

Comment: I have added braces `{}` around the `\sim` in the quotient to make it look better. $\Bbb R^n/\sim$ vs $\Bbb R^n/{\sim}$. You can revert it if you wish.

Comment: I see my original question was very poorly worded - I hope it makes more sense now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the equivalence relation. Differentiability is defined in smooth manifolds, and any quotient of a smooth manifold may not be another manifold. From what you say it seems that you have studied manifolds inmersed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but this seems like it could be better understood by studying manifolds in an abstract setting. A reference for that is $\textit{Introduction to Smooth Manifolds}$, by Lee.

The result you are interested in can be found in the 2$^{nd}$ edition of the book as theorem 21.13 (9.13 in the 1$^{st}$ edition). Your equivalence relation is given by a discrete group acting freely and properly in $\mathbb{S}^2$ (see example 21.14), so the quotient is a manifold (diffeomorphic to the projective plane, $\mathbb{P}\mathbb{R}^2$).
This means that we have a smooth quotient map $\pi:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}/{\sim}$. In the case of discrete groups (like in your example), the map $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Now to answer the question, if a map $\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$ is smooth, then the map $\pi\circ f:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}/{\sim}$ is smooth (as it is a composition of smooth maps). Now as you say, the condition $f(x)=f(-x)\;\forall x$ means that from $\pi\circ f$ we can obtain a well defined function $g:\mathbb{S}/{\sim}\to\mathbb{S}/{\sim}$. Moreover smoothness can be checked locally, and locally the function $g$ is given by $f\circ\pi^{-1}$, which is differentiable because $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism.

PS: $\textit{Introduction to Smooth Manifolds}$ is the main book I´ve used to study smooth manifolds but I don´t know if it´s the best reference for quotients of manifolds by group actions at this level, anyone with a better reference is welcome to edit the answer.

Comment: I'll leave it to others to comment on whether _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ is the "best" reference for this purpose. But I just want to point out that the citation you gave about quotients by discrete groups (Theorem 9.19) is in the first edition; for those who have the second edition, the analogous result is Theorem 21.13.

Comment: Thanks! Edited. About the reference thing, I just thought that the proposition would be hard to read for someone who I suspect has only studied the basics of manifolds on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But after thinking again, the topic of quotients doesn´t make much sense in manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I don´t know if a more elementary treatment of the subject is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, the result I wanted to prove is exactly $\mathbb{S}^2/\sim \cong_{diff} \mathbb{PR}^2$, as you mentioned. Whilst I don't doubt the theorems required to show this, do you know if there is an explicit construction of this result?